# How to label only certain x-ticks matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, xticks

In this diagram I have distributed the ticks and applied a tick:

```
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 800, 1))
ax.grid()
```

How can I label on the x-axis only the numbers present in the legend?

[image: Plot]

Regards,

Karl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to keep all grid points, but only label the points of interest.

```
original_labels = [str(label) for label in ax.get_xticks()]
labels_of_interest = [str(i) for i in np.arange(235,295,5)]
new_labels = [label if label in labels_of_interest else "" for label in original_labels]
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
```

Edit:

an optional parameter to `ax.set_xticklabels` is `rotation`. If you find your labels are still overlapping, try rotating them:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels, rotation=45) #rotate labels 45 degrees
```

Comment: Thank you! It works.